# iphone variable problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

```
// stampDuty percentages
    float stamp1 = (invalue * 1 / PCENT);
    float stamp2 = (invalue * 2 / PCENT);    // #defined PCENT as 100

// stamp duty
    NSNumber *stampN1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:stamp1];
    NSNumber *stampN2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:stamp2];

// then goes to 
// Stamp Duty invalue is entered in the textfield by user
    if (invalue <= 125000.0f) {

    NSLog(@"Equal to or under 175,000 1% Stamp Duty");

//stampN0
   [lblIntrest setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Stamp Duty: %@", [currencyStyle stringFromNumber:stampN1]]];    
//  need a common variable variable is picked up here
// the value that is calculated here is used with other totals to create a grand final total


    }

    if (invalue >= 125001.0f && invalue <= 250000.0f) {

        NSLog(@"Greater than 125,000 and less than 250,000 StampDuty 1%%");
            [lblIntrest setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Stamp Duty: %@",[currencyStyle stringFromNumber:stampN2]]];
//   need a common variable is picked up here

    }

// returns with the appropriate value
//the value that is calculated here is used with other totals to create a grand final total.
//  eg float Beven = (invalue + SaleP + stamp1 etc etc
```

If I use stamp1 in the above calculation it works fine. What I'm looking for is a common variable to enter into this calculation variable "string". There are other `if` statements.
Hope you can help

Comment: Please reformat this so the code is readable. As it stands, it's difficult to parse the question...

Comment: Please rewrite your question in plain text i.e. outside the code block. You seem to assume we know what this code does and we don't. Clearly write out what behavior you want to see and what behavior you are seeing now. E.G. You say stamp1 works fine but you don't say what "works" means or what something other than stamp1 produces.

Comment: Oh, and give the question a more meaningful title. "iphone variable trouble" is way, way to vague.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the variable name `actualStampValue`.

Also note, your code contains two errors:

1. Your first if checks that the number is <=125000, but the string it prints says 175000.
2. Your second if checks that the number is >=125001, which leaves out all the values in between 125000 and 125001. This check should be >125000.